# Expected value of exponential function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gamma-function, means, beta-function

Suppose two identical component are connected in a piece of factory equipment. The two lifetimes X1 and X2 are independent each having exponential distribution with beta =2. The value of the equipment after three years of use is 200(0.6^X1+X2). Calculate the expected value of the equipment after three year.

So I started with E(200(0.6^X1+X2)), but how to take down the X1+X2?
Btw the X1+X2 follow gamma distribution with alpha and beta = 2.

Comment: It looks like you intend $200((0.6)^{X_1}+X_2)$, but sometimes people are not so good about parentheses, so it might be $200(0.6)^{X_1+X_2}$. Which one is it?

Comment: The second one. 200( 0.6^(X1+X2) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of $X_1$ and $X_2$, I will use $X$ and $Y$. The random variable $X$ has density function $(0.5)e^{-(0.5)x}$ for $0\le x\lt \infty$, and $0$ elsewhere.  The random variable $Y$ has density function $(0.5)e^{-(0.5)y}$ for $0\le y\lt \infty$, and $0$ elsewhere. Thus by independence the joint density function of $X$ and $Y$ is
$$(0.5)^2 e^{-(0.5)x}e^{-(0.5)y}$$
in the first quadrant $Q_1$, and $0$ elsewhere. It follows that 
$$E(200(0.6)^{(X+Y)})=\iint_{Q_1} 200(0.6)^{x+y}(0.5)^2 e^{-(0.5)x}e^{-(0.5)y}\,dx\,dy.\tag{1}$$
Now we need to integrate. Note that $$(0.6)^t =e^{\ln(0.6)t}=e^{-\ln(1/(0.6))t}.$$
 So the integral (1) can be rewritten as
$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty 50 e^{-kx}e^{-ky}\,dx\,dy,$$
where $k=\ln(1/0.6)+0.5$.

Integrate. We get 
$\dfrac{50}{k^2}$.